# Api call for getting the size of data being processed on query level

Tags: google-bigquery

On the bigquery UI, we can see total size of the data processed.
How we can get that information as part of a call and later in the week or month as asynchronous call? Synchronous calls may not show us to total data being process as the channel can get broken and bq might continue to process and charge the usage thus we need to make an asynchronous call to fill up the gaps. Using GetQueryResultsResponse class to stream the data our in a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve it by either the [jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) or [jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) method.  Once the job has completed, either API call should expose the amount of bytes processed by a query job in the field [statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed).

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the ["jobs" list API call](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) and check the totalBytesProcessed 
field. As long as you are using the same user, you should be allright